# How can i select one distinct column from more than 2 columns

Tags: php, mysql

I want select more than 2 columns from db, How can i select one distinct column from among those..

sample query

> select id,name,intime,outtime,date from `reports`;

in above query i want to select "id" as distinct.

Comment: Unless things are weird, `id` should be unique

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select id,name,intime,outtime,date 
from reports
group by id
```

[mysql's extensions to group by](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html) allow you to select columns that are not in the group by clause. Note that for columns not specified in the group by clause, the server is free to choose any value from the group.

Answer (score 2):

Using distinct?

`select DISTINCT id,name,intime,outtime,date from reports;`

Comment: PS. The ID should be unique so distinct doesnt have any added value.